# Por que não consigo adicionar a barra de menus em um wx.Frame?

Tags: python

Caros,
Em uma tela, construída com WxPython, deveria ter um menu "Arquivo", com os itens "Importar", "Exportar" e "Sair".
O código roda sem erro, a janela é exibida com o seu título, mas o menu não é mostrado. Qual terá sido o erro que cometi?

import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, title):
    super(MainFrame, self).__init__(None, title = title)

    self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    self.filemenu = FileMenu()
    self.menubar.Append(self.filemenu, '&Arquivo')
    self.SetMenuBar(self.MenuBar)

    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)
```

class FileMenu(wx.Menu):

```
def __init(self):
    super(FileMenu, self).__init__()

    self.importitem = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_NEW, text = '&Importar\ctrl+i', kind = wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
    self.exportitem = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_NEW, text = '&Exportar\ctrl+e', kind = wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
    self.quititem = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.ID_NEW, text = '&Sair\ctrl+q', kind = wx.ITEM_NORMAL)

    self.Append(self.importitem)
    self.Append(self.exportitem)
    self.Append(self.quititem)
    self.AppendSeparator()
```

app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame('Exemplo')
app.MainLoop()

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Seria tão bom se houvesse uma mensagem de erro. Ocorre que não há.
Com o código acima, uma janela é exibida, porém, o menu não é adicionado.
Não consigo imaginar outra pergunta senão: o que está errado no código.
Se estes detalhes não forem suficientes, eu compreendo e agradeço do mesmo modo.
Se houver outros detalhes que aqui não incluo, é porque de fato nada mais me ocorre.